# adding image in between v-for in vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to add images later, but I am using `v-for`, and **I don't know what to do to add the image in between without breaking the loop.**

```html
<template>
  <v-card>
    <p v-for="item in texts" :key="item.id" class="bm-1">{{ item.text }}</p>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue } from "nuxt-property-decorator";

export default class QuickStart extends Vue {
  texts: any[] = [
    {
      id: 0,
      text: "Text A",
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "Text B",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "Text C",
    },
  ];
}
</script>
```

For example, in the code above, I want to add an image between id 1 and 2, but how? (And I want to use the `v-for` too. If that wasn't the case, I know I could have just added numbers or `p` tags.)

**I tried to put an image with an `id` and `text`, but as expected, it didn't work.**

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

You can create it in multiple ways. One thing is certain: the array must be well-structured. For example, a possible approach could be that some elements of the array contain text, while other elements contain images, and you display them sequentially. This way, the first element is text, the second is an image, and the third can be another text variation.

```js
const { createApp, reactive } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const list = reactive([{
      id: 1,
      text: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,
molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum
numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium
optio, eaque rerum!`
    }, {
      id: 2,
      imageSrc: "https://picsum.photos/200/300"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      text: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,
molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum
numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium
optio, eaque rerum!`
    }])

    return { list }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item of list">
    <div v-if="item.text">{{ item.text }}</div>
    <div v-if="item.imageSrc">
      <img :src="item.imageSrc" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Solution # 2

Alternatively, you can decide to associate an image with each of the texts they belong to. For example, I choose to have 2 texts, and the second one is associated with an image:

```js
const { createApp, reactive } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const list = reactive([{
      id: 1,
      text: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,
molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum
numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium
optio, eaque rerum!`
    }, {
      id: 2,
      imageSrc: "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
      text: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,
molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum
numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium
optio, eaque rerum!`
    }])

    return { list }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item of list">
    <div v-if="item.imageSrc">
      <img :src="item.imageSrc" />
    </div>
    <div v-if="item.text">{{ item.text }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Solution # 3

If you want to consistently position an image between the 1st and 2nd elements, as well as between the 2nd and 3rd elements, etc., you can declare them in the HTML template as well. You just need to use a v-if condition to specify when they should appear.

```js
const { createApp, reactive } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const list = reactive([{
      id: 1,
      text: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,
molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum
numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium
optio, eaque rerum!`
    }, {
      id: 2,
      text: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,
molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum
numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium
optio, eaque rerum!`
    }, {
      id: 3,
      text: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,
molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum
numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium
optio, eaque rerum!`
    }, {
      id: 4,
      text: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia,
molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum
numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium
optio, eaque rerum!`
    }])

    return { list }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item of list">
    <!-- Pre-Declared Image between ID-1 and ID-2 -->
    <img v-if="item.id === 2" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="between 1 and 2" />
    
    <!-- Pre-Declared Image between ID-2 and ID-3 -->
    <img v-if="item.id === 3" src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="between 2 and 3" />
    
    <!-- Pre-Declared Image between ID-3 and ID-4 -->
    <img v-if="item.id === 4" src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" alt="between 3 and 4" />

    <!-- Text -->
    <div v-if="item.text">{{ item.text }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Summary

In summary, what you are asking for can be achieved in many different ways. The image should always have its place in your array, either as a separate item or associated with another item.